# UWP ComboBox not populating with bound value

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, uwp

I'm writing a UWP app and have a few comboboxes bound to my view model. For some reason the comboboxes aren't updating the bound value nor loading it when they render if I set the values manually while debugging. I see that this is a common issue but I can't spot any of the causes I've seen other people have so far. Following is my stripped down code:

**XAML:**

```
<Page
x:Class="UWPApp.Scorekeeper.SelectGoalTime"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:UWPApp.Scorekeeper"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Name="MainElement">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}">
    <ComboBox x:Name="MinutesSelect" SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=MainElement,Path=ViewModel.Minutes}" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainElement,Path=MinutesList}"/>
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using UWPApp.Scorekeeper.Interfaces;
using UWPApp.Scorekeeper.Models.ViewModels;
using UWPApp.Scorekeeper.Models.TransportClasses;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using UWPApp.Scorekeeper.Models;
using UWPApp.Scorekeeper.Toolbox;

namespace UWPApp.Scorekeeper
{
    public sealed partial class SelectGoalTime : Page
    {
        public AddGoal_FVM ViewModel { get; set; }

        public List<int> MinutesList { get; set; } = Enumerable.Range(0,21).ToList();

        public SelectGoalTime()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            var message = e.Parameter as GoalMessage;
            ViewModel = message.ViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

**AddGoal_FVM**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace UWPApp.Scorekeeper.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class AddGoal_FVM
    {
        public int Minutes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you try to use INotifyPropertyChanged, you must call NotifyPropertyChanged in the setter of the bounded property: public int Minutes {set{NotifyPropertyChanged();}} and you must set the DataContext in the SelectGoalTime class.

Comment: Oops, forgot to remove that implementation. It shouldn't affect this issue since the value isn't changing outside of page load and selection (i.e. this property doesn't need the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation). Why would my list bindings work without setting the DataContext if that was necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have the reputation to add a comment, I'll have to share this way:

Found here, https://twitter.com/kdawg02/status/746734845393518592, BUG UWP ComboBox SelectedValue has to be the last property in XAML otherwise it will not set the value on load.

Hope it helps, I had no end of troubles with trying to bind a combobox in UWP with the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have fixed it. It does seem to be loading the value in the view model, but it isn't setting it.